# JList setSelectedValue not working

Tags: java, list, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a `JList` in Swing working bad. I list all items from Database into the list with no problem with this code.

My code:

```
Integer index = null;

DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
index = DataBase.getIndex1(cbActivity.getSelectedItem().toString());
activities = DataBase.getIndex2(index); 

for(MapActivity mapActitivy : activities)
{
   model.addElement(mapActivity.getActivity().toString());
}    
jList.setModel(model);
```

But now, I would like to select individual or multiple selection, but nothing I tried works. I tried:

```
jList.setSelectedValue("Ball", true);
//jList.setSelectedIndex(2);
jList.setSelectionBackground(Color.red);
```

But nothing happen. Just the list on screen with nothing selected. Single or multiple.

Any help?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: As I just tried to reproduce your problem, I was not able to do so. For me both ways work just fine

Comment: Find out if value "Ball" from model is exactly equal to the one you want to select. Try to print them out to the console and check if dont contain any spaces or sth.

Comment: Yes the value Ball is the same as DataBase. The list is printed correctly, but the code below dows not select any value in red.

Comment: Just to double check: insert this line "model.addElement("Ball");" before selecting "Ball" and see if sth has changed

Comment: @WojciechWirzbicki Ball is duplicated in the list but all white, none selected.

Comment: Strange, have you tried doing invalidate, repaint on the list? Maybe you perform selection from outside awt thread?

Comment: Good idea @WojciechWirzbicki I added jList.revalidate(); jList.repaint(); after selection but nothing happen again. The selection is called after list is painted when charge the GUI, pressing a button , nothing special.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176233/discussion-between-deathgun-and-wojciech-wirzbicki).

Comment: @WojciechWirzbicki *"..have you tried doing invalidate, repaint on the list?"* None of that should be necessary. OP: Where is the MCVE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setSelectedIndex(1); // here use index of items

or if it does not work use below one:

setSelectedItem("ball") // here use name of item.
```